# Single install Apache Karaf with failover configuration using shared disk

Tags: apache-karaf, failover, apache-servicemix, master-slave

I'm looking to implement failover (master/slave) for Karaf. Our current
server setup has two application servers that have a shared SAN disk where
our current Java applications are installed in a single location and can
be started on either machine or both machines at the same time.

I was looking to implement Karaf master/slave failover in a similar way
(one install being shared by both app servers), however I'm not sure that
this is really a well beaten path and would appreciate some advice on
whether the alternatives (mentioned below) are significantly better.

**Current idea for failover:**
Install Karaf once on the shared SAN and setup basic file locking on this
shared disk.
Both application servers will effectively initiate the Karaf start script,
however only one (the first) will fully start (grabbing the lock) and the
second will remain in standby until it grabs the lock (if the master falls
over)

The main benefit I can see from this is that I only have to manage
deploying components to one Karaf installation and I only need to manage
one Karaf installation.

**Alternatives:**
We install Karaf in two separate locations on the shared SAN and setup to
lock to the same lock file.
Each application server will have their own Karaf instance, thus start
script to run.

This will make our deployment slightly more complicated (2 Karaf
installations to manage and deploy to).

I'd be interested if anyone can indicate any specific concerns that they
have with the current idea.

Note: I understand that Karaf-cellar can simplify my Karaf instance
management, however we would need to undertake another round of PoCs etc..
to approve our company use of cellar (as a separate product). Something
that I'd like to migrate to in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_ha_failover_and_cluster)

This is from the documentation on how to set a lockfile for HA:

```
karaf.lock=true
karaf.lock.class=org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock
karaf.lock.dir=<PathToLockFileDirectory>
karaf.lock.delay=10000
```

as can be seen there, you can also set a level for the bundle start-levels to start or not to start:

```
karaf.lock.level=50
```

Comment: Thanks, I think by setting the karaf.lock.level to 1 then this seems like a valid setup. Cheers